# Arranging code in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a development environment where modules are
divided into libraries and applications.
The application needs to import a module that is not installed
as a package into the main python packages.
Both the application and the libraries are continuously modified.

This is the directory layout of the files.  Files from one project may be reused by other projects, and thus cannot be in the same directory tree.

```
projA\lib\util.py
projA\lib\other.py
projB\lib\another.py
projC\src\app1\app1.py
```

So far, the best I could come up with is the following, 
which causes problems for IDEs code completion because of the dynamic imports

```
# app1.py
import sys
sys.path.append('../../../projA/lib')
import util
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Comment: Yes, this path would be different for each application, according to its dependencies.  This means that in order to use it, I would need a shell script that sets the env path, runs the .py and then reverts to the original path.  I would rather handle all such paths and dependencies in python code, to make it self sufficient

Comment: In that case, there's probably no better way. If the main problem is with the IDE, then maybe you need a better IDE?

Answer (score 2):

How about using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org), and installing your other projects as libraries in the virtual system path.

Most Python IDE's support virtualenv and have no problems with code-completion.

Also it is a good practice making it easy to distribute your project and managing dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use virtualenv or dynamic imports,

you can add your modules path to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

[PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Note: you might have to create this environment variable, assuming you are using Windows OS, you can use (from command line):

`setx PYTHONPATH folder1;folder2;etc`

[setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

Comment: I would rather avoid using environment vars.  Assume a scenario where a developer checks out a directory tree like this and should be able to run code without doing any kind of setup.

Comment: Even not a single value, lets say `PYTHONPATH` to `c:\workspace` and  there you would have some `settings.py` which imports `/projA/lib` and the rest? Then there is a single env var "installed" once.

Comment: This would require a settings.py for each set of imports I need.